# Getting error CS1955: Non-invocable member 'SceneManager' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the scene to reload when the player triggers the lose condition(by dieieng), in order to create a checkpoint system of sorts. This game is an FPS btw in case that is relevant.

Here is the relevant code:

```
string m_SceneToLoad;
```

.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (gameIsEnding)
        {
            float timeRatio = 1 - (m_TimeLoadEndGameScene - Time.time) / endSceneLoadDelay;
            endGameFadeCanvasGroup.alpha = timeRatio;

            AudioUtility.SetMasterVolume(1 - timeRatio);

            // See if it's time to load the end scene (after the delay)
            if (Time.time >= m_TimeLoadEndGameScene)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(m_SceneToLoad);
                gameIsEnding = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (m_ObjectiveManager.AreAllObjectivesCompleted())
                EndGame(true);

            // Test if player died
            if (m_Player.isDead)
                EndGame(false);
        }
    }
```

.

```
void EndGame(bool win)
    {
        // unlocks the cursor before leaving the scene, to be able to click buttons
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        Cursor.visible = true;

        // Remember that we need to load the appropriate end scene after a delay
        gameIsEnding = true;
        endGameFadeCanvasGroup.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        if (win)
        {
            m_SceneToLoad = winSceneName;
            m_TimeLoadEndGameScene = Time.time + endSceneLoadDelay + delayBeforeFadeToBlack;

            // play a sound on win
            var audioSource = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
            audioSource.clip = victorySound;
            audioSource.playOnAwake = false;
            audioSource.outputAudioMixerGroup = AudioUtility.GetAudioGroup(AudioUtility.AudioGroups.HUDVictory);
            audioSource.PlayScheduled(AudioSettings.dspTime + delayBeforeWinMessage);

            // create a game message
            var message = Instantiate(WinGameMessagePrefab).GetComponent<DisplayMessage>();
            if (message)
            {
                message.delayBeforeShowing = delayBeforeWinMessage;
                message.GetComponent<Transform>().SetAsLastSibling();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            
            Scene scene = SceneManager().GetActiveScene;
            m_SceneToLoad = scene.name;
            m_TimeLoadEndGameScene = Time.time + endSceneLoadDelay;
        }
    }
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error. Please help.
EDIT: Error is at this line: `Scene scene = SceneManager().GetActiveScene;`

Comment: It would be good if you said where the error is, then we didn't have to search. I pressume it's here:  `Scene scene = SceneManager().GetActiveScene;` Apparently, `SceneManager` is not a method, but a property.

Comment: @PMF correct, i'll add it

Comment: @PMF [`SceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) is a **type** not a property. [`SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) however is a method ;)

Comment: @derHugo Duh, so it was the other possibility. I actually guessed on this one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

[`SceneManager`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.html) is a **type** not a property. [`SceneManager.GetActiveScene()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene.html) however is a static method ...

It is supposed to be

```
var scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene();
```